# Why do propellors have white markings on their tips?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller, piston-engine, engine-design, turboprop

Why do propellors have white markings on their tips?

Here are a couple of examples:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is so you will see a circle when they are turning.  Without contrasting bright tips turning propellers are invisible, and pose a grave risk for someone who is deaf, wearing heavy hearing protection, or distracted by other noises.

Comment: ie: [in moving pictures](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-4817462-one-propeller-two-engine-plane-running-high)

Comment: @J..., excellent video!  Do you mind if I add that to my answer for completeness?  (It was late last night when I answered...)

Comment: Sure.  It's not mine - I just grabbed a link from shutterstock.

Comment: On second thought, I think links are discouraged in answers because they can expire and break.

Comment: Yes, but that's largely if the substance of the answer is contained in the link.  In this case it's just supporting material - the answer stands alone without it.  That said, there are also some nice stills in the dupe so...